# How to deal with negative Z score problems

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Given mean life time of 40 days and standard deviation of $1.25$ days. If $12\%$ of the cars produced are having a maximum lifespan of $n$ days, find the value of n.

My work::

$Z = \dfrac{X- 40}{1.25}$

$P (X<n) = 0.12$

Using normal table conversion,

$\dfrac{X- 40}{1.25} = -1.175$

$X = -1.175(1.25)+40$

$X = 38.5325 $ days

Is the $Z$ value correct? As per the statement, the maximum of $n$  days $(X<n)$ but it gives negative $Z$ score.

Comment: 12 out of how many cars?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Aruha meant to write 12% of the cars.

Comment: @Aruha : to show % you have to type \%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative Z score is **perfectly fine**.

Z-distribution (=Standard Normal Distribution) follows
Normal Distribution with mean=0 and standard deviation=1.

That is, Z ~ N(0, 1)

*The support of Z-distribution is in between **-infinity and +infinity**.*

Thus, your Z-score can be any negative numbers or positive numbers.

This Wikipedia will show you the Z-table of negative and positive Z-values as well as the density function of Z-distribution on the right side if your scroll down a bit. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table

I hope you find this helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct. Note that the variable is $n$, not $X$ in the last three lines. $n$ was expected to be less than the mean $40$ otherwise $P(X<n)$ would have been greater than or equal to $0.5$, which is not the case.